# space-conscious character for Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping, spatial, hololens

I'd like to do something like to that of the video in minute 3:09
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYdB2xBNFek

I think that I need the Spatial Mapping and Spatial Understanding, but I can't understand how can I create a space conscius character. I'd like that this character could go on the sofà, and on to other fornitures as in the video that i put before.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the [Spatial Awareness System](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/SpatialAwareness/SpatialAwarenessGettingStarted.html) in MRTK (it is enabled by default), you only need to add a Collider component on this game object, it will have physical interaction with the generated Spatial Mesh.

However, I think what you really need is the "Tap To Place". To implement it in MRTKv2.3, the [Solver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html) would be a good direction. The [SurfaceMagnetism Solver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#surfacemagnetism) can cast rays to surfaces in the world, and align the object to that surface. Besides, in the upcoming MRTKv2.4 , [TapToPlace](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_TapToPlace.html) will be released as a new function of MRTK, which allows you to easily place the object in the scene.