# Characters with space awareness for Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I've seen a similar question to mine in this website([space-conscious character for Hololens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693147/space-conscious-character-for-hololens/61742765#61742765)), but I'd like to explain more precisely what I want to do. I'd like to do the same of the following video in the minute 3:09: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYdB2xBNFek

I've read that a user has replied with some suggestions. In particular, the use of Spatial Awareness System or the use of Solver system. But I don't understand how them could help for what I want to do. Online there are very few tutorial of those systems.

More precisely, for my project I have some characters and all of them have to have awareness of the space. For example, like in the video, those characters have to jump from the sofà to another forniture. In brief, they have to understand the space around them.

How can I do? Do you also think that the Spatial Awareness System and the Solver system are the best methods? Do you know any tutorials that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand how them could help for what I want to do

Spatial Awareness System of MRTK provided a collection of meshes, representing the geometry of the environment, which allowed for compelling interactions between holograms and the real-world. And Spatial Awareness System provide a convenient and rapid path for getting started with Spatial mapping. Therefore, it is the core feature to realize your ideas.

If you are not familiar with Spatial mapping you can start with [Spatial mapping in unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-mapping-in-unity#higher-level-mesh-analysis-spatialunderstanding). For how to use Spatial Awareness System, please refer to [Spatial Awareness](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/SpatialAwareness/SpatialAwarenessGettingStarted.html)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Online I've seen that Spatial Awareness is avaiable only for Hololens 2 while I have Hololens 1. So, what can I use in order to replace Spatail Awareness System?

Comment: Spatial Awareness System is available both for Hololens1 and HoloLens2. You may be confused it with [scene understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/scene-understanding).

Comment: Thanks Sorry but I'm very confused. If you can help me, I have another question. Reading on the Internet I saw that there are Space Mapping, Spatial Understanding and now Spatial Awareness. The goal of my project is to use characters from a story that the user can interact with in his room.

I split the messange in two messages

Comment: So these characters must be able to move around the room without sinking into the ground and without crossing objects. Therefore, the difference between spatial mapping, reading and awareness escapes me. It seems to me that everyone does the same thing.

An additional goal would be to make sure that these characters, initially placed on a specific room, can fit into any room. Do you have some advice? I thank you for your availability and kindness

Comment: Scene understanding provides you with a superset of functionality from Spatial mapping. The bulk of the power and complexity lies in access patterns, interaction with 3D frameworks, and tools that can be written on top of these APIs to perform more advanced tasks like spatial planning, room analysis, navigation, physics etc. On the contrary, if your application requires the lowest-latency possible and mesh triangles that only you will want to access, use Spatial Mapping directly.

Comment: For Spatial Awareness System of MRTK, it provides a convenient and rapid path for getting started with Spatial Mapping. Spatial Awareness System does not implement additional features itself but, instead, defines the Spatial Observer that allows your app to work with functionality common to multiple platforms.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late. I have another question: can I do the spatial mapping (and undestranding and spatial awareness) not in my real room but in a model 3D room?